# Why does this function work to determined wether or not an input of an Integer is Odd or Even in Swift?

Tags: swift, math

```
func isOdd(n: Int) -> Bool {
    if n % 2 == 1 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

So this function basically has me confused. let's say I called the function and input 9

```
isOdd(in:9)
```

I know that 9 is an odd number but how does the code work. If I do the math that the code implies which is n(9)/2 it equals 4.5. This result is checked as implied by the 2 equal symbols with 1. 4.5 is not equal to 1 so why does it return True.

Comment: Notice there's **%**, not **/**

Comment: % is the modulus operator, not the division one.  If this still doesn't make sense you need to look it up.

Comment: You should use BinaryInteger [isMultiple(of:)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0225-binaryinteger-iseven-isodd-ismultiple.md) method. It will be much easier to understand what the code does `!n.isMultiple(of: 2)` or if you prefer `n.isMultiple(of: 2) == false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modulus division, gives the reminder when the first int is divided by the second int
and it `returns an int`. So `n % 2` returns `0` or `1` as a `int` reminder.
That is why your function works. You can simplify your function to this:

```
func isOdd(n: Int) -> Bool { n % 2 != 0 }
```

Comment: The shift from `== 1` to `!= 0` actually changes the semantics, but in a good way: it now correctly handles negative numbers.